# what is happening behind the scenes in diamond inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I wrote a code in C++ using diamond inheritance without using the keyword 'virtual' for the top-most class A while defining classes B and C which inherit A. Then I defined the class D which inherits from B and C. As the class D does not use class A member x, compilation does not throw any error. But if it does (by uncommenting the function foo()), compiler throws error mentioning ambiguity which is understood.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class A
{
protected:
  int x;
public:
  void set(int y){x=y;}
};

class B:public A
{
};

class C:public A
{
};

class D:public B,public C
{
public:
  // void foo(){x*=2;} // error!
};

int main()
{
  cout<<sizeof(D)<<endl;
  return(0);
}
```

The foo() function is allowed by using 'virtual' qualifier while defining classes C and D as shown below for class C.

```
class C:virtual public A
{
};
```

Now there is not any ambiguity for x used in foo() as there is only single copy of it. My question is hence this:

a) In the first case did the compiler actually allow 2 copies of x as it did not have to resolve any ambiguity?

b) If answer to (a) is yes, then why did the first code output 8 for the size of class D and the second code output 24 for the same? As the first case has two copies of x, should not its size be at least as much as in the second case (even if we ignore padding)?

Comment: a) yes, you'll have `B::x` and `C::x`, which are distinct. 2) virtual bases have extra overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) Yes.  It is actually duplicated.  To be explicit, D contains the members B::x and C::x.

If you modify foo() to be explicit, it can work.  For example:

```
void foo() { B::x *= 2; }
```

b) The reason extra memory is taken up in virtual inheritance case, is the need for the virtual table or vtable.

You can find a good explanation here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html